# select2 multiselect - select a group and all its children but allow more than one child to be selected when the group is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, multi-select

Using the jQuery plugin select2 multiselect how would you select a group and all its children but allow more than one child to be selected when the group is not selected? Below you will find a jsfiddle that allows the group to be selected but only one child can be selected at a time. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

jsfiddle select2 multiple - http://jsfiddle.net/jcUUG/145/

**HTML CODE:**

```
<input type='hidden' id='select'>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
$(function () {

var select2_ary = [];

select2_ary.push(

{id: 'numbers', text: 'numbers',
    children: [
        {id: "numbers", text: "1"},
        {id: "numbers", text: "2"},
        {id: "numbers", text: "3"},
        {id: "numbers", text: "4"},
        {id: "numbers", text: "5"}
    ]
}, 
{id: 'letters', text: 'letters',
    children: [
        {id: "letters", text: "A"},
        {id: "letters", text: "B"},
        {id: "letters", text: "C"},
        {id: "letters", text: "D"},
        {id: "letters", text: "E"}
    ]
}
);

$("#select").select2({
    placeholder: "Select",
    data: select2_ary,
    multiple: true,
    width: "300px"
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same id for more than one option, that's why you are getting this behaviour.

Look at this [Select2 with multiple nested groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146848/select2-with-multiple-nested-groups)