# Select2 multi level not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to build a select2 with multi level options, but seems like the third level options don't work...

I've found a couple of snippet and the issue is reproducible:

```
$('#test').select2({
    placeholder: 'Search for an option',
    multiple: true,
    data: [{
            text: 'Level_1',
            children: [{
                    text: 'Level_2',
                    children: [{
                            id: 'Level2Opt0',
                            text: 'Sub Option 1'
                        }, {
                            id: 'Level2Opt1',
                            text: 'Sub Option 2'
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    id: 'Level1Opt0',
                    text: 'Main Level option 1'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
});
```

[JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/tmpb57nh/1/)
[JSFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/fr0z3nfyr/5uu7rL18/)

I've read that there is a problem nesting optgroup in HTML, but I'm setting my options on JS side, when calling select2 function.

I'm not sure if there is any solution to this problem, but I haven't found one.

Cheers!

Comment: Lobo is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/5uu7rL18/21/

Comment: Maybe this does help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146848/select2-with-multiple-nested-groups

Comment: Thanks Carsten, that looks like a solution. Only problem is that the "parents" shouldn't be clickable, but I guess I can solve that with some class/js